# How to add a clear button for a python kivy painting app

Tags: python, button, canvas, kivy, kivy-language

I am building a basic painting app with python and kivy for learning app development. I am trying to figure out how to clear the canvas after drawing on the screen by modifying the code on the .kv file.

Within the .kv file I think I need to modify the #on_release:root.canvas.clear()
portion of the code, currently it deletes the entire canvas and buttons. I am trying to figure how to make it so that it just clears the screen only, allows to redraw on the screen again, and does not erase the buttons.

Heres a picture for context
[Painter App](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tqKqj.png)

What happens after pressing the clear button
[Blank Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HwKpV.png)

```
from random import random
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen, FadeTransition
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.graphics import Line, Color, Ellipse

class Painter(Widget):
    def on_touch_down(self, touch):
    color = (random(), 1.,1.) #reduce number of possible colors
    with self.canvas:
        Color(*color, mode='hsv') #sets the colors to be equally bright
        d = 30.
        Ellipse(pos=(touch.x - d / 2,touch.y - d / 2), size=(d,d))
        touch.ud["line"] = Line(points=(touch.x, touch.y))


def on_touch_move(self, touch):
    touch.ud["line"].points += [touch.x, touch.y]

class MainScreen(Screen):
    pass

class AnotherScreen(Screen):
    pass

class ScreenManagement(ScreenManager):
    pass

presentation = Builder.load_file("main3.kv") #load the kivy file

class SimpleKivy7(App):
    def build(self):
        return presentation

if __name__== "__main__":
    SimpleKivy7().run()
```

The following is the kivy file

```
#: import FadeTransition kivy.uix.screenmanager.FadeTransition

ScreenManagement:
    transition: FadeTransition()
    MainScreen:
    AnotherScreen:

<MainScreen>:
    name: "main"
    Button:
        on_release: app.root.current = "other"
        text: "Next Screen"
        font_size: 50

<AnotherScreen>:
    name: "other"

FloatLayout:
    Painter
    Button:
        color:0,1,0,1
        font_size: 25
        size_hint: 0.3, 0.2
        text: "Back Home"
        on_release: app.root.current = "main"
        pos_hint: {"right":1, "top":1}

    Button:
        color:0,1,0,1
        font_size: 25
        size_hint: 0.3, 0.2
        text: "Clear"
        #on_release:root.canvas.clear() #root.canvas.clear() clears everything. 
        pos_hint: {"left":1, "top":1}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I assume that the code you provided is just a part of your codebase. I encountered some errors that I would like to clear up: there was no indentation from line 10 after the `Painter` `def on_touch_down`, I indented lines 10-17 once. In the `.kv` file there were two widgets kivy considered as root widgets (there can only be one). I added `<` and `>` around your screen manager `ScreenManagement` on line 3. I am also sorry to say that in my case the app only draws the circles, but not the lines after them.

The problem lies on line 34 in the `.kv` file: `on_release: root.canvas.clear()`. The `root` refers to the `FloatLayout`. So you're clearing all that is on the `FloatLayout` including the buttons. What you need to clear is the `Painter` widget's canvas. Add an `id` to your `Painter` and clear its canvas instead:

```
FloatLayout:
    Painter:
        id: painter # an id for referring to this widget
    Button:
        color:0,1,0,1
        font_size: 25
        size_hint: 0.3, 0.2
        text: "Back Home"
        on_release: app.root.current = "main"
        pos_hint: {"right":1, "top":1}

    Button:
        color:0,1,0,1
        font_size: 25
        size_hint: 0.3, 0.2
        text: "Clear"
        on_release:  painter.canvas.clear() # clear the Painter's canvas
        pos_hint: {"left":1, "top":1}
```

Comment: Thank you very much!
 I added the id:painter like you suggested 
and for the clear button I added on_release: painter.canvas.clear()
The button now clears the canvas only!